# How to sync only Facebook contacts that already exists in phone for Android 2.2

Tags: sync

Device: Samsung Galaxy Fit
Android: 2.2 Froyo

How can I sync only the Facebook contacts which already exists in my phone memory? I don't want to sync the contacts that are not on my phone memory.

Answer (score 1):

You could choose to only show contacts that have phone numbers. If I remember correctly, this is in `Contacts` -> <kbd>Menu</kbd> -> `Display options` -> `Only contacts with phones`.

Another possible solution is to go to `Settings` -> `Accounts & sync` and remove the Facebook sync, `Add account` -> `Facebook` and in this process select `Sync existing contacts only`.

I'm not 100% sure about the menu item names, but they should be somewhat similar. It's been a while since I've used Froyo.

Comment: Whether `Facebook` shows up under `Accounts & Sync` will depend on your ROM and what apps it comes with or you have installed.